# MSDeploy skip root web.config

Tags: msdeploy

I can't get `msdeploy` to skip only the root web.config (I want to keep any web.config files that exist in sub folders below the root)

This is the parameter I am using:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=^\\web\.config
```

I have tried `^\\web\.config`, `\\web\.config` and the absolute path to the file, e.g.: `C:\\Some Path\\web\.config`. None of those seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to sort this out.

You have to use the full *source* path in order to skip the *target* root web.config only. `msdeploy` appears to use the source path for this regex filter.

like this:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=\\\\servername\\c\$\\syncpath\\web\.config
```

Hope this helps somebody else out in the future.

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

On top of this, if you are skipping a web.config file in  a sub directory you also need that target dir and web.config in the regex, like so:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=\\\\servername\\c\$\\syncpath\\web\.config|TargetFolder\\web\.config
```

This will stop msdeploy from issuing a delete directive on the target web.config.

Note that the regex compare is case-insensitive.

Comment: How can we do this without specifying the full path

Comment: You can use a relative path but it wouldn't make sense if copying from another server